# How can I get a c variable from cgo?

Tags: go, cgo

```
package main

/*
#include <malloc.h>
#include <windows.h>
HDC *hdcArr

BOOL CALLBACK EnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (_msize(hdcArr) / sizeof(HDC)); i++) {
        if (hdcArr[i] == NULL) {
            hdcArr[i] = hdcMonitor;
            break;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
void Init() {
    int count = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS);
    hdcArr = (HDC*)malloc(sizeof(HDC) * count);
    memset(hdcArr, 0, sizeof(HDC) * count);
}
HDC* GetHDC() {
    return *hdcArr;
}
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
    ".../w32"
)
func main() {
    var hdc w32.HDC
    hdc = w32.GetDC(0)
    C.Init()
    w32.EnumDisplayMonitors(hdc, nil, reflect.ValueOf(C.EnumProc).Pointer(), 0)
    t := (*[]w32.HDC)(unsafe.Pointer(&C.hdcArr))
    cx := w32.GetDeviceCaps((*t)[0], w32.HORZRES)
    fmt.Println(cx)
}
```

I wrote the source code as above.

What I want is to import cgo's HDC array into a w32.HDC array to know the width and height values of each monitor.
However, if you import `t: = (* [] w32.HDC) unsafe.Pointer (& C.hdcArr))` and call `cx: = w32.GetDeviceCaps ((* t) [0], w32.HORZRES)` Only 0 is returned.

How can I use cgo to find the width and height of multiple monitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```golang
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lgdi32
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <windows.h>
HDC *hdcArr;
int count;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (_msize(hdcArr) / sizeof(HDC)); i++) {
        if (hdcArr[i] == NULL) {
            hdcArr[i] = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcMonitor);
            break;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
void Init() {
    count = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS);
    hdcArr = (HDC*)malloc(sizeof(HDC) * count);
    memset(hdcArr, 0, sizeof(HDC) * count);
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"

    "github.com/JamesHovious/w32"
)

func main() {
    C.Init()
    hdc := w32.GetDC(0)
    w32.EnumDisplayMonitors(hdc, nil, reflect.ValueOf(C.EnumProc).Pointer(), 0)
    w32.ReleaseDC(0, hdc)
    t := (*[256]w32.HDC)(unsafe.Pointer(C.hdcArr))[:C.count:C.count]
    for _, dc := range t {
        cx := w32.GetDeviceCaps(dc, w32.HORZRES)
        fmt.Println(cx)
        w32.DeleteDC(dc)
    }
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(C.hdcArr))
}
```

It's very important for you to understand, that a pointer to a C-Array is just a memory address without any information about size (hence why your t array was empty). This is why you have to cast it to a big array first `(*[256]w32.HDC)` and then slice it to the right size `[:C.count:C.count]`

That's why i made `count` a global variable.

The other issue you ran into was that the hdc handles passed to `EnumProc` were only valid inside the callback. To make them permanent and usable outside the callback scope, you have to call `CreateCompatibleDC(hdcMonitor);`. 
To use this function with cgo you will have to include the lib gdi32 via `#cgo LDFLAGS: -lgdi32`

Once you are done using these DC's you have to free them again with `w32.DeleteDC(dc)`

Also don't forget to free your malloced array with `C.free(unsafe.Pointer(C.hdcArr))`

My advice: Whenever you use a WinApi, carefully read the msdn documentation. It takes some time, but saves you lots of trouble

You can also do this entirely in golang without cgo:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"

    "github.com/JamesHovious/w32"
)

func EnumProc(hMonitor w32.HMONITOR, hdcMonitor w32.HDC, lprcMonitor *w32.RECT, dwData w32.LPARAM) uintptr {
    fmt.Println(w32.GetDeviceCaps(hdcMonitor, w32.HORZRES))
    return w32.TRUE
}

func main() {
    hdc := w32.GetDC(0)
    w32.EnumDisplayMonitors(hdc, nil, syscall.NewCallback(EnumProc), 0)
    w32.ReleaseDC(0, hdc)
}
```

or even smoother:

```golang
func EnumProc(hMonitor w32.HMONITOR, hdcMonitor w32.HDC, lprcMonitor *w32.RECT, dwData w32.LPARAM) uintptr {
    horzres := lprcMonitor.Right - lprcMonitor.Left
    fmt.Println(horzres)
    return w32.TRUE
}

func main() {
    w32.EnumDisplayMonitors(nil, nil, syscall.NewCallback(EnumProc), 0)
}
```